# Attach FPDF result to PHP Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fpdf

I have been banging my head against a wall with this and have searched this site and others regarding how to fix:

I have two forms, one in a popup that a user completes to fill out a quote, then that dialog closes and it goes back to the main form for communicating back to the customer and attaches a PDF of the quote. everything works fine until I try to not make it open in a new window or attach to the existing form. I have successfully called it via ajax, but I am not receiving results, though the temp file it makes is correct on the server.

JS to submit quote to makepdf.php:

```
    function generatepdf(forminfo) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(form).attr("action"),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: forminfo,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#qmessage").html("Preparing quote..");
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#qmessage").html(data);
                            //$('.multifile:last').val(data);
                        }
                    });
                };
```

PHP of makepdf.php:

```
$pdf_filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "pdf");
if(!file_exists($pdf_filename) || is_writable($pdf_filename)){
        $pdf->Output($pdf_filename, "F");
    } else { 
        exit("Path Not Writable");
    }
$pdf->Output($pdf_filename, F);
echo $pdf_filename;
```

It is not writing the result to the qmessage div, but does save the file on the server. I did not see a way that made sense to me for attaching the server side file back to the existing `<input type="file" class="multifile">` field.

Edit: Both forms are on the same page, so passing variables between them would not be an issue. It is getting the FPDF output back into the page and getting that attached to the other form (which should be doable via the .val() function?)

Comment: to clarify: there is no requirement to save the file to the server, I just need to get it back into the parent form to send on to the client. I went this direction because i thought it might simplify the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with attaching it to the form in a  is that the file is already server side (the temp file it created ....)

what you COULD do is attach the output (file path to that file) to a hidden input to process on your second form ... for example:

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $(form).attr("action"),
  type: 'POST',
  data: forminfo,
  beforeSend: function() {
      $("#qmessage").html("Preparing quote..");
  },
  success: function(data) {
      $("#hidden_input").val(data);
  }
});
```

PHP of makepdf.php:

```
$pdf_filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "pdf");
if(!file_exists($pdf_filename) || is_writable($pdf_filename)){
    $pdf->Output($pdf_filename, "F");
} else { 
    exit("Path Not Writable");
}
$pdf->Output($pdf_filename, F);
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/" . $pdf_filename;
```

And then the secondary form:

```
...
-- HTML the jQuery will set the value --
<input type="hidden" name="generatedpdf" id="hidden_input" value="">
```

And finally the processor PHP:

```
...
$file_location = $_POST['generatedpdf'];
// Code here to deal with pdf
// after finished - remove temperary pdf:
unlink($file_location);
...
```

Not 100% sure if this is what you are expecting for the final output - but it is an option ...
Cheers!

Comment: I guess my code makes that confusing, I don't actually need to save the file to the server, it just needs to go into the form to send on to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying it is creating file on server, this means FPDF library is installed properly and working fine.

Now the issue arises with sending output as file name, so that javascript could print it using AJAX request.

Kindly check if you execute directly just by typing the url and parameters in Browsers, does FPDF library returns  file name you are looking for. If no, then there might be issues with php headers, that are sent before file output.

PHP headers might be sent before, try to use ob_start function, so that issues with sessions may not occur.

Comment: so issues are with headers use output buffer. ob_start() to keep output during execution of script.

Comment: but it is outputting the name correctly, so the headers are working, correct?